# Spring sleuth generates 2 traceId s for one http request

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:1.3.2.RELEASE. For each request to the rest endpoint entires with two different traceId s are generated. Below is a sample log output for one complete request.

two traceIds: ce67bb66181b4368 & b228413a4cdd6eb8

{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.052+00:00","trace":"ce67bb66181b4368","span":"ce67bb66181b4368","parent":"","exportable":"false","pid":"12856"}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.055+00:00","trace":"ce67bb66181b4368","span":"ce67bb66181b4368","parent":"","exportable":"false","pid":"12856"}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.055+00:00","trace":"ce67bb66181b4368","span":"ce67bb66181b4368","parent":"","exportable":"false","pid":"12856"}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.131+00:00","trace":"ce67bb66181b4368","span":"ce67bb66181b4368","parent":"ce67bb66181b4368","exportable":"false","pid":"12856","stack_trace":"o.s.w.c.HttpClientErrorException: 403 ..."}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.147+00:00","trace":"ce67bb66181b4368","span":"ce67bb66181b4368","parent":"ce67bb66181b4368","exportable":"false","pid":"12856","stack_trace":"o.s.w.c.HttpClientErrorException: 403 ..."}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.163+00:00","trace":"ce67bb66181b4368","span":"ce67bb66181b4368","parent":"ce67bb66181b4368","exportable":"false","pid":"12856","stack_trace":"o.s.w.c.HttpClientErrorException: 403 ..."}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.178+00:00","trace":"","span":"","parent":"","exportable":"","pid":"12856","stack_trace":"o.s.w.c.HttpClientErrorException: 403 \r\n\tat o.s.w.c.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:85)\r\n\tat o.s.w.c.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:707)\r\n\t... 75 frames truncated\r\n"}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.194+00:00","trace":"b228413a4cdd6eb8","span":"b228413a4cdd6eb8","parent":"","exportable":"false","pid":"12856"}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.194+00:00","trace":"b228413a4cdd6eb8","span":"b228413a4cdd6eb8","parent":"","exportable":"false","pid":"12856"}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.194+00:00","trace":"b228413a4cdd6eb8","span":"b228413a4cdd6eb8","parent":"","exportable":"false","pid":"12856"}
{"timestamp":"2018-02-14T14:18:19.194+00:00","trace":"b228413a4cdd6eb8","span":"b228413a4cdd6eb8","parent":"","exportable":"false","pid":"12856"}

Flow:
Rest client(postman) (calls)-> serviceA (calls)-> serviceB. ServiceB rejects the call with 403 and the same is propagated to the rest client - flow working as expected
Issue is ServiceA is logging entries which have two different trace ids.

both serviceA and serviceB are spring boot apps.

Do not have any sample app. these are services I am working on. Doing nothing unusaual.

Added the dependency "spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:1.3.2.RELEASE" in the pom and updated logback-spring.xml config with encoder LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder.

Please advise. Thanks,

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This tells us nothing. I have no idea how your application looks like, what exactly you are doing, how the app is configured etc. Please upload your sample somewhere.

Comment: Hi Marcin, updated the flow in the description.

Comment: I can't help you without the samples, sorry.

Comment: I've been updating the configs; application properties etc and this issue  disappeared at some point I did not observe. Thanks for your time any way.